# Open Lexicon for classified affective words

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm looking for lexicons like [POMS](http://www.mhs.com/product.aspx?gr=cli&prod=poms&id=overview) or [ANEW](http://csea.phhp.ufl.edu/media/anewmessage.html) that classify words, especially adjectives, into the 6 "universal" emotions: "anger, disgust, fear, happiness, sadness, and surprise" by Paul Ekman or using [Russel's approach](http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/healey/tweet_viz/figs/circumplex.png).

Do any of you know a lexicon that is free to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the structure provided by [wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) for synonym sets of adjectives:

> The most frequently encoded relation among synsets is the super-subordinate relation (also called hyperonymy, hyponymy or ISA relation)

I'm not sure, however, if this hierarchy will lead you to the 6 emotions you're looking for.

A valuable set of resources, by Saif Mohammad, including the NRC Emotion Lexicon available [here](http://www.saifmohammad.com/WebPages/lexicons.html) - I think that is closer, except it's not limited to adjectives.

Another promising wordnet extension for affect words [here](http://wndomains.fbk.eu/wnaffect.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing out. I've already looked into Wordnet affect but unfortunately it doesn't provide much words... However this answered my question in the best possible way.

Comment: Update: The best resource I've found is ConceptNet (http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/). You can use a basic affective lexicon and then search for connecting links in the graph structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could try building such a classifier using twitter data!

Get a large corpus/stream of tweets and filter it out to the ones that contain emoticons.
Use maybe [this mapping of emoticon to emotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons#Western) to guess the sentiment of each tweet and extract the adjectives off that tweet in order to build a adjective histogram for each emotion.
Some postprocessing of that list should give you what you are looking for!

The [TweetNLP library](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/) has a POS tagger that will probably be useful for you!

Comment: Something similar is done in the NRC Hashtag Emotion Lexicon - based on 'seed' hashtags for different emotions :) See links in the other reply.

Comment: [Pak and Paroubek 2010](http://lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2010/pdf/385_Paper.pdf) are known for this idea.

One of the risks with doing this is that people often use emoticons sarcastically, or at least not redundantly. Just a quick search of twitter for ":)" shows Tweets like: 
"How's your week going? :)",
"I'm a lil elf :)", and
"OMG 6 DAYS FOR MY BIRTHDAY AND ALL MY FAMILY WILL FORGET LIKE EVERY OTHER YEAR BECAUSE ITS ON CHRISTMAS EVE :-) :-) :-)".

So the results may not be... ideal. After all, "forget", "elf, and "week" don't indicate positive sentiment.

Comment: I think it's called distant supervision now and there are many techniques to statistically overcome these issues :)

Comment: This is an idea I had before too. To be specific: I wanted to create a captcha using Tweets, letting people classify adjectives in them. Unfortunately this doesn't really answer my question, right...